# PHP: How to clear form after submit and show success alert?

Tags: php, html, forms

I've been having trouble with PHP (new to php) to clear my form fields AFTER a successful submission. I would also like to show an alert that it was successful. Any ideas? Using javascript with the onclick listener for the submit button will not work because it clears the fields before PHP has time to send the data.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="col-lg-7 mt-5 mt-lg-0 d-flex align-items-strech" data-aos="fade-left">
  <form id="contact-form" action="contact-form-handler.php" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 characters"/>
        <div class="validate"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="name">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter at valid email"/>
        <div class="validate"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Subject</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter a subject of at least 8 characters"/>
      <div class="validate"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="10" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please enter a message"></textarea>
      <div class="validate"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];


  $email_from = "Portfolio Email";
  $email_body = "Name: $name.\n".
                "User Email: $visitor_email.\n".
                "User Message: $message.\n";

  $email_to = "email@gmail.com";

  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

  mail($email_to, $subject, $email_body);
?>
```

Comment: Showing alerts and clearing forms are client side activities and would be best performed with javascript. What you should to do is collect the data from your form via javascript, then display your alert and clear your form, then submit your data to your form handler via ajax.

Comment: if you like your form to post data to a url, and onSuccess you want to show an alert in the same page, then use ajax post

Answer (score 0):

If you do **not** want to use ajax, please try the following
(assuming the html is known as "form.html", and the php is "contact-form-handler.php")

The php redirection to form.html will clear the input fields (a normal behavior in web-browsers), and the javascript will show the word "successful" as an alert.

Please make further adjustment(s) according to your needs.

form.html

```
<div class="col-lg-7 mt-5 mt-lg-0 d-flex align-items-strech" data-aos="fade-left">
  <form id="contact-form" action="contact-form-handler.php" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 characters"/>
        <div class="validate"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="name">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter at valid email"/>
        <div class="validate"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Subject</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter a subject of at least 8 characters"/>
      <div class="validate"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="10" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please enter a message"></textarea>
      <div class="validate"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
  </form>
</div>


<script>
function get(name){
   if(name=(new RegExp('[?&]'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'=([^&]*)')).exec(location.search))
      return decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
}

</script>


<script>
if (get("result")=="success")
{
alert("Successful");
}
</script>
```

contact-form-handler.php

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];


  $email_from = "Portfolio Email";
  $email_body = "Name: $name.\n".
                "User Email: $visitor_email.\n".
                "User Message: $message.\n";

  $email_to = "email@gmail.com";

  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

  mail($email_to, $subject, $email_body);
?>
<script>
window.location.href="form.html?result=success"
</script>
```